# Prolog: show a list contained within a list

Tags: prolog

I currently have the following facts defined in a Prolog program:

```
hobbies([jarrod, [gaming, running, boxing]]).
hobbies([james, [programming, gaming, drawing]]).
```

What query could display a list of jarrod's hobbies? (i.e. [gaming, running, boxing])

Comment: `?- hobbies([jarrod, Hobbies]).`  Still I'd prefer to rephrase it like

Comment: .. having facts `hobbies(jarrod, [gaming, running, boxing]).`

Comment: ?- hobbies([jarrod, Hobbies]).
This keeps producing the error... 
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: hobbies/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: For starters, there's a syntax error in the above.  Does hobbies take one array argument, or two arguments?

Comment: my fault, hobbies should take one argument. hobbies([Name, [ListOfHobbies]]).

Comment: @jarrodparkes: But it would be preferable to have two arguments!

Answer (score 1):

@false is correct:

`hobbies([jarrod, Hobbies]).`

it unifies hobbies against all the facts, and then only gets the ones where the first element of the list is jarrod.  Then it unifies Hobbies with the list of hobbies.